# Spark 1.6 Data Frame - convert all field values in struct to uppercase

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Have the following data frame and using Spark 1.6

```
scala> dfShow.printSchema
root
 |-- email: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- EML: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EMT: string (nullable = true)
```

This reads fine from source json. How can I convert the all the values to uppercase? Show on data frame gives

```
scala> dfShow.show 
[{"EML":"a.b@c.COM","EMT":"b"},{"EML":"d.e@x.COM","EMT":"h"}]
[{"EML":"g@g.COM","EMT":"h"},{"EML":"f@f.com","EMT":"x"}]
null
[{"EML":"j@j.org","EMT":"b"},{"EML":"r.r@r.COM","EMT":"t"}]
```

How do I change the values in 2 fields EML and EMT to be upper case? Would like the fields to look as follows

```
[{"EML":"A.B@C.COM","EMT":"B"},{"EML":"D.E@X.COM","EMT":"H"}]
[{"EML":"G@G.COM","EMT":"H"},{"EML":"F@F.com","EMT":"X"}]
null
[{"EML":"J@J.org","EMT":"B"},{"EML":"R.R@R.COM","EMT":"T"}]
```

This is one struct field. I have other struct fields like address (line1,line2,city,state,zip,country) , phone etc. Is there a generic way to convert values for all struct fields to upper?

Comment: If by generic you mean one which doesn't require UDF and matching individual fields then not really, unless you count hacks like converting to json, calling upper, converting from json.

Comment: You can use the schema to get all fields within a struct object, use map to loop through the fields and use the upper() spark function, then create a struct from the resulting object. For the case of array ( struct (string, string ) ) you'll have to explode first.